# How do I deserialize a class that has an nlohmann::json object as its first constructor parameter?

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have a class that expects an `nlohmann::json` object as its first constructor parameter. I've implemented `to_json` and `from_json` for my class, but `from_json` doesn't get called (unless I call it explicitly) and the default deserialization just puts the entire object into the `json` parameter. Here is some example code.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::json;

class ExampleClass
{
public:
  ExampleClass(json data = json::object(), std::string some_string = "") : m_Data(data), m_String(some_string) {}
  ~ExampleClass() {}

  json m_Data;
  std::string m_String;
};

void to_json(json& j, const ExampleClass& example)
{
  j = json{ {"Data", example.m_Data}, {"String", example.m_String} };
}

void from_json(const json& j, ExampleClass& example)
{
  j.at("Data").get_to(example.m_Data);
  j.at("String").get_to(example.m_String);
}

int main()
{
  ExampleClass example(json{ {"key", "value"} }, "here's a string");
  std::cout << json(example) << std::endl; // {"Data":{"key":"value"},"String":"here's a string"}

  ExampleClass example_two = json::parse("{\"Data\":{\"key\":\"value\"},\"String\":\"here's a string\"}");
  std::cout << json(example_two) << std::endl; // {"Data":{"Data":{"key":"value"},"String":"here's a string"},"String":""}

  ExampleClass example_three;
  from_json(json::parse("{\"Data\":{\"key\":\"value\"},\"String\":\"here's a string\"}"), example_three);
  std::cout << json(example_three) << std::endl; // {"Data":{"key":"value"},"String":"here's a string"}
}
```

As you can see, explicitly calling the `from_json` method that I wrote works fine, but I've read you're not supposed to do that. I've used this pattern for dozens of classes elsewhere in my project and only came across this problem with classes that need a `json` object as their first (or only) constructor parameter. Putting a non-json parameter first makes everything work fine, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong that this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you don't actually want to call the constructor in the case of `example_two`. As such, you should make your constructor `explicit` to avoid accidental calls.

```
class ExampleClass
{
public:
  explicit ExampleClass(json data = json::object(), std::string some_string = "") : m_Data(data), m_String(some_string) {}
  ~ExampleClass() {}

  json m_Data;
  std::string m_String;
};
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Tr1YxTa5j

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! I knew I was just missing something simple.

Comment: @ZippoBibrok5e8 Glad that it helped. As a general rule, if you have a constructor that can take only one argument (as is the case here, there are two parameters but both of them are defaulted), you should mark the constructor as `explicit` unless you have clear reason to do otherwise. I even believe it should really be the default in  C++ language but you know, there are already too many incorrect defaults in C++ due to backward compatibility.

Comment: With C++11, even 0 parameter or 2+ parameter constructors should probably be marked `explicit`, unless after due consideration it is warranted not to do it.  (Not including the copy-constructor and move-constructor, which should not be marked `explicit`... unless there is a very good reason to mark either of them `explicit` and with awareness of the (opt-in) problems that can cause).  C++:  all the defaults are wrong.